# Fancy Header: Alternating Centered Headers

Tags: fancyhdr

How can I can have centered chapter title on odd pages, and centered section title on even pages?

Comment: Use e.g. `\fancyhf[coh]{odd header}\fancyhf[ceh]{even header}`.

Comment: That did not work for me.

Comment: I'm glad you have an answer but next time, please provide an MWE. 'Doesn't work' is singularly unhelpful. It could mean just about anything from your computer exploding to the dog eating the plug to successful compilation but with unexpected or undesired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the interface provided by [`titleps`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps), which easily captures the section unit titles. The change in interface from [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) is described in [`titleps` for `fancyhdr` users](http://www.tex-tipografia.com/titleps_fancyhdr.html):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext,titleps}
\newpagestyle{chapsec}{
  \setheadrule{.4pt}
  \sethead[\thepage]% <even left head>
    [\thesection.\ \sectiontitle]% <even centre head>
    []% <even right head>
    {}% <odd left head>
    {\thechapter.\ \chaptertitle}% <odd centre head>
    {\thepage}% <odd right head>
}
\pagestyle{chapsec}
\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```